# Proving set of polynomials of degree less than $n$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, polynomials

$P_n$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$ where the norm is defined as $\|f-g\| = \sup |f-g|$ where $x$ is restricted to $[0,1]$. In addition the coefficients are reals restricted to the domain $[0,1]$. 
How would one show this subspace is closed. I know I have to show that all its limit points are also in $P_n$.

Comment: You may want to state this question more precisely.  It isn't clear what the definition of $P_n$ is.

Comment: Hint: $P_n$ is a finite-dimensional subspace. The whole subspace of polynomials of any degree is not closed, though, given Weierstrass approximation. So you might want to edit your title.

Comment: Is the problem to prove that polynomials of degree less than or equal to n with coefficients from [0,1] is a closed subspace of C[0,1]?

Comment: Yes, except degree is less than n, not equal, not much of a difference either way.

Comment: Are you sure the coefficients are supposed to be from [0,1]?  This is not a linear subspace.  It still seems like a weird problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to show that ANY finite dimensional linear subspace of $C[0, 1]$ is closed.

Comment: Would it work to prove that the subspace is closed, if the result was asking to prove that it is closed with respect to norm